# Cannot reset artifactory admin password in docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, artifactory

I am running Artifactory V7.71.5 in a Docker container. I am trying to reset my password and am having difficulty doing so.

I have found many variations of ways to reset the password for At=rtifactory on the Internet, but all of the instructions are geared toward Ubuntu or AWS EKS installations. No one (not even the JFrog folks!) seems to provide reset instructions for doing a reset on a Docker installation.

I have tried using docker exec and following some of the instructions I found, but most of those are for earlier versions of Artifactory and the files and directories in the container are different from the ones described in the instructions!

Can someone provide or point me to instructions for resetting an admin password on an up- to- date Docker installation of Artifactory???

Comment: I don't know artifactory. `... but most of those are for earlier versions of Artifactory and the files and directories in the container are different from the ones described in the instructions!` But why not `exec` into the docker container and follow the instructions you found for Ubuntu, AWS, ... ?

Comment: As I stated in the beginning of the paragraph you are quoting from, I *have* been exec'ing into the container. That is how I found out that the instructions for earlier Artifactory versions don't work for the current version!

Comment: Did you create the bootstrap.creds file?

Comment: Yes, and my question was, did you try the instructions for the current version (that are not related to docker)  with the `exec` approach? It should be easy to apply what is described in [Admin User Recovery](https://jfrog.com/help/r/artifactory-how-to-unlock-a-user-s-who-is-locked-out-of-artifactory-and-recover-admin-account/admin-user-recovery) to docker `$JFROG_HOME/artifactory/var/etc/access` is likely in a volume, so changes are persistent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reset the admin user credentials (or create a new admin user) by following the below steps:

1. exec into the container
2. Create the "bootstrap.creds" file by running `echo "newadmin@*=password" > /var/opt/jfrog/artifactory/etc/access/bootstrap.creds` (just change the username and password)
3. Change the file permission to 600 by running `chmod 600 /var/opt/jfrog/artifactory/etc/access/bootstrap.creds`
4. Change the file ownership by running `chown 1030:1030 /var/opt/jfrog/artifactory/etc/access/bootstrap.creds`
5. Restart to container

There is additional information on this process in [this KB](https://jfrog.com/help/r/artifactory-how-to-unlock-a-user-s-who-is-locked-out-of-artifactory-and-recover-admin-account/admin-user-recovery).